# call_user_func_array throws an error when the method exist

Tags: php

This is how I am reaching the `_call` method:

```
$model->delivery_price = $currencyConverter->convertPriceByGivenCurrencies(
                        $model->delivery_price,
                        $currency->id,
                        $model->order_currency
                    );
```

The function throws an error but the method exists below it. My `__call` looks like:

```
public function __call($name, $params)
    {
        if(method_exists(CurrencyConverter::className(), $name)){
            if($params[0] == 0 || $params[0]){
                call_user_func_array($name, $params);
            }else{
                throw new \Exception('Price must be a valid number!');
            }
        }
        throw new NotFoundException('Function doesn\'t exist');
    }
```

It passes the `if` condition but after that the error occures:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'convertPriceByGivenCurrencies' not found or invalid function name
```

And this is the `convertPriceByGivenCurrencies` method which is landed in the below the `_call`:

```
protected function convertPriceByGivenCurrencies($product_price, $product_price_currency_id, $select_currency_id)
    {
      ............
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Thank you!

Comment: When you are checking whether the method name exists, you are passing a class name to do so. But where in your `call_user_func_array` call are you referring to that same class …? You are passing the function name only there, so it looks for a standalone _function_ of that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$name` by itself is not a known function; it seems to be a method in the `CurrencyConverter` class.

So to call it, assuming it is a static method, you would need something like:

```
CurrencyConverter::$name(...$params);
```

Note that you need the `...` operator to [unpack](http://php.net/functions.arguments#functions.variable-arg-list) `$params`

Comment: But the unpacking is avaible in 5.6 only. At least this is what the PHPStorm says :)

Comment: @TomaTomov That's right, if you are on an earlier version you should probably upgrade :-)

Comment: In fact I am on `PHP Version 7.2.6-1`. it is not usable on higher version ?

Comment: @TomaTomov It is available from 5.6 on, so you can use it without any problems. Does PHPStorm know you are on 7.2?

Comment: Guess he doesn't know because it is working :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Calling it with

```
call_user_func_array($name, $params);
```

it is expecting a standalone function called `$name`.

As it's a method in a class you need to add this information to the [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), if you want to call it on the current instance then use

```
call_user_func_array(array($this,$name), $params);
```

If it isn't a method in the current instance, then replace `$this` with the appropriate instance.  Or change the method to be `static` and replace `$this` with the class name.

Comment: `__call` and `protected function convertPriceByGivenCurrencies` are both in `CurrencyConverter` class. And the variable `$currencyConverter` is instance of the `CurrencyConverter` class. Sorry about the unclear explanation :)

Comment: Your answer also works and both gave me some new knowledges. I wish I could mark more than 1 best answers. Thank you very much!